# Reading escape characters from json into python

Tags: python, json

I want to read in a list of escape characters into python from a json config file.

For example, the end result python list would be `my_list = ['\x02','x\03']`

However, I can't figure out how to represent this in json as they don't read `\x..` as a character.

```
{
    ...
    "my_list": ["\x02", "\x03"],
    ...
}
```

How would I represent this list in json so it is correctly imported to python?

Comment: Look into the json module for encoding and decoding json objects

Comment: That `my_list = ['\x02','\x03']` looks like a sequence of bytes, not a string. One standard way of encoding bytes as strings (so it becomes JSON friendly) is via [base64](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try it out by using json.dumps:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(['\x02','x\03'])
'["\\u0002", "x\\u0003"]'
>>> json.loads('["\\u0002", "x\\u0003"]')
['\x02', 'x\x03']
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful ^^